# How can I implement Auto calculated field in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a collection of workorders where it have `time_started` and `time_completed` values. I want to have auto-calculated field called `duration` that automatically calculated `time_completed - time_started`. What is the best way?
Essentially what I want is, when App post requests with a completed time, my duration is auto calculated.
[Example data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZPxk.png)

```js
router.post('/completed', function (req, res) {
  const time_completed = req.body.time_completed
  const workorder_id = req.body.workorder_id

  db.collection(workorder).updateOne(
    { _id: ObjectId(workorder_id) },

    {
      $set: {
        time_completed: time_completed,
      }
    },

    function (err, result) {
      if (err) throw err
      res.send('Updated')
    }
  )
});
```

Comment: if you can next time send the data at JSON text, so people can test their queries on them.

Comment: _Your code_ literally is the auto-calculator. If you want duration, either compute it and include it in your documents, or you can add [stored JS](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/store-javascript-function-on-server/#store-a-javascript-function-on-the-server) to your db, but stored JS slows everything down, and unless you're absolutely certain you need it, you don't. Your code can remap values either before saving them to, or after getting them from,  mongodb just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query

- pipeline update requires >= MongoDB 4.2
- add the `time_completed`
- add the `duration` also

*replace the 6 with the javascript variable that holds the `time_completed` Date
*duration will be in milliseconds

[Test code here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/W3WHhWiSFDp)

```js
db.collection.update(
{"_id": 1},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "time_completed": 6,
      "duration": {
        "$subtract": [
          6,
          "$time_started"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

---

**Edit**

You have strings on your database, i thought it was dates, best thing to do is to convert all those string-dates to Date with `$dataFromString` like the code bellow, and use the first query.

To get the string if you needed from Date you can do `$stringFromDate` when you need it.

Query

- same like above but it converts string dates to Date to do the substraction (keeps the dates in strings inside the database)

[Test code here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ewX0pfaDLh9)

```js
db.collection.update({
  "_id": 1
},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "time_completed": "2021-11-21T00:00:00.000Z",
      "duration": {
        "$subtract": [
          ISODate("2021-11-21T00:00:00Z"),
          {
            "$dateFromString": {
              "dateString": "$time_started"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Thanks. But my query gives an error. $subtract cannot subtract strings. My date time_started and time_completed are in ISODate format.

Comment: i updated it to work for dates as strings, but we shouldn't save strings if we have dates, for many reasons, like performance etc

Comment: It worked. thanks.
even the previous query worked for me eventually. Turns out, my POST route will injecting date string instead of Date.